# (Java)Using while function with condition

Tags: java, new-operator

I am making program that add all the number from user input until 0 comes. when 0 comes as input, I want to show all the numbers that are saved. When I run the program I got the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" this error and I want to know what part is wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    
    while(a!=0) {
        myList.add(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(myList.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: How do you expect your loop to terminate since you never change `a` inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO a `for` loop is more appropriate:

```
for (int a = scanner.nextInt(); a != 0; a = scanner.nextInt()) {
    myList.add(a);
}
```

This has the desirable effect of limiting the scope of `a` to the loop (one should always limit the scope of everything as much as possible).

Comment: I would argue that this solution suffers from poorer readability than solutions that use `while`; and that readability is a valuable attribute of most programs.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem readability is important. But scope is more so: It's not clear that `a` is not used after a `while`. A `for` loop reinforces the way loop iterates. Whether a `for` or `while` is used, separate calls to `scanner.nextInt()` must be made - one for initialization, one for iteration, but they are aspects of a single *intention*. It's clearer to collect them together with syntax.

Comment: I have to agree with @DawoodibnKareem on this one--an input loop which should terminate when a character is reached is almost exclusively written with a while loop. While I very much appreciated the clever approach you took with the for loop here, I think anyone reading the code would struggle to understand what it does, whereas reading that standard while loop is much more logical.

Comment: @Bohemian I disagree with pretty much everything in your comment.  But that's OK.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep reading a new number from stdin. Otherwise, `a` will not change value, and will lead to said error:

```java
while (a !=0) {
  myList.add(a);
  a = scanner.nextInt();
}
```